# How to get path parameters from path using Java

Tags: java, regex, path-parameter

I have a path `/departments/{dept}/employees/{id}`. How do I obtain `dept` and `id` from path `/departments/{dept}/employees/{id}`?

For example, I would like to obtain `dept1` and `id1` if path is `/departments/dept1/employees/id1`

I tried

```java
String pattern1 = "departments/"
String pattern2 = "/employees"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2));
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
   String a = m.group(1);
}
```

Is there a simpler way to obtain dept1 and id1? I would prefer not using string.split as I have different paths for which I want to obtain path parameters and I prefer not having a dependency on the index position of the path parameters.

Comment: Are you using any Frameworks like Spring MVC or JAX-WS/JAX-RS ?

If not, you could use a regular expression with groups

Comment: What do you have against String.split?

Comment: Yes, you can use RegEx with capturing groups.

Comment: @user3706481, you can use AntPathMatcher spring utility class, check at my answer for more details

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Spring framework`, then you can use a class specifically for this purpose named [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) and use its method [extractUriTemplateVariables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html#extractUriTemplateVariables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

So, you can have the following:

```
AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();

String url = "/departments/dept1/employees/id1";
String pattern = "/departments/{dept}/employees/{id}";

System.out.println(matcher.match(pattern, url));
System.out.println(matcher.extractUriTemplateVariables(pattern, url).get("dept"));
System.out.println(matcher.extractUriTemplateVariables(pattern, url).get("id"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring... or:

```
String url = /departments/{dept}/employees/{id}
             /----none--/-dept-/---none---/-id-
```

Make a split of url and get the position of array 1 and 3:

```
String urlSplited = url.split("/");
String dept = urlSplited[1];
String id = urlSplited[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer regix:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

        public class ExampleUnitTest {

        @Test
        public void test_method() throws Exception {

            Pattern digital_group = Pattern.compile("[//]");

            CharSequence line = "test/message/one/thing";

            String[] re = digital_group.split(line);

            for (int i=0;i<re.length;i++) {

                System.out.println(re[i]);

            }

        } 

    } //END: class ExampleUnitTest
```

The output is:

```
test
message
one
thing

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Pattern.compile("test/\\w+?/one/\\w+") helped to obtain message and thing. Thanks.

Comment: May be check the every result part with another pattern? What your task exactly? If you want exctract second part - it's simple re[1]. If you check it with the some known rule...

Comment: String result =re[1].concat(", ").concat(re[3]);